# Twitter pagination for home_timeline API not working

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-timeline

I am using twitter home_timeline API for showing tweets.
For first time I run this it works fine, but when I call it again (pull to load more), it doesn't responds. I am passing auth headers and in params I passed count, it doesn't worked too.
I don't know where am I stuck..

Here is code for pulling tweets:

```
if (auth != null && auth.token_type.equals("bearer")) {

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL);

    String oAuthConsumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY;
    String oAuthConsumerSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET;

    String oAuthAccessToken = HomeActivity.twitter_access_token;
    String oAuthAccessTokenSecret = HomeActivity.twitter_access_token_secret;

    String oAuthNonce = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String oAuthSignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
    String oAuthTimestamp = time();
    String oAuthVersion = "1.0";
    String signatureBaseString1 = methods;
    String signatureBaseString2 = TwitterStreamURL;
    String signatureBaseString3Templ = "oauth_consumer_key=%s&oauth_nonce=%s&oauth_signature_method=%s&oauth_timestamp=%s&oauth_token=%s&oauth_version=%s";
    String signatureBaseString3 = String.format(signatureBaseString3Templ,
            oAuthConsumerKey,
            oAuthNonce,
            oAuthSignatureMethod,
            oAuthTimestamp,
            oAuthAccessToken,
            oAuthVersion);

    String signatureBaseStringTemplate = "%s&%s&%s";
    try {
        signatureBaseString = String.format(signatureBaseStringTemplate,
                URLEncoder.encode(signatureBaseString1, "UTF-8"),
                URLEncoder.encode(signatureBaseString2, "UTF-8"),
                URLEncoder.encode(signatureBaseString3, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        compositeKey = URLEncoder.encode(oAuthConsumerSecret, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(oAuthAccessTokenSecret, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        String oAuthSignature = computeSignature(signatureBaseString, compositeKey);

        oAuthSignatureEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(oAuthSignature, "UTF-8");

        String authorizationHeaderValueTempl = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"%s\", oauth_nonce=\"%s\", oauth_signature=\"%s\", oauth_signature_method=\"%s\", oauth_timestamp=\"%s\", oauth_token=\"%s\", oauth_version=\"%s\"";

        String authorizationHeaderValue = String.format(authorizationHeaderValueTempl,
                oAuthConsumerKey,
                oAuthNonce,
                oAuthSignatureEncoded,
                oAuthSignatureMethod,
                oAuthTimestamp,
                oAuthAccessToken,
                oAuthVersion);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String vf = "oauth_consumer_key=" + oAuthConsumerKey + ",oauth_signature_method=" + oAuthSignatureMethod + ",oauth_timestamp=" + oAuthTimestamp + ",oauth_nonce=" + oAuthNonce + ",oauth_version=" + oAuthVersion + ",oauth_token=" + oAuthAccessToken + ",oauth_signature=" + oAuthSignatureEncoded + "";
    httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + "oauth_consumer_key=" + oAuthConsumerKey + ",oauth_signature_method=" + oAuthSignatureMethod + ",oauth_timestamp=" + oAuthTimestamp + ",oauth_nonce=" + oAuthNonce + ",oauth_version=" + oAuthVersion + ",oauth_token=" + oAuthAccessToken + ",oauth_signature=" + oAuthSignatureEncoded + "");
        httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // update the results with the body of the response
    checkTwitRes = true;
    results = getResponseBody(httpget);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
div {
    color:#000;
    font-weight:800
}

p {
    color:red;
    background:url("mypicture.png")
}
```

Comment: irrelevant css answer to the java / android question